# Tkinter open with 1Button the directory of 2 Buttons and save a Textfile

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I wanted to make a code to search for file names like `*.bsp`, save the names in a text file, delete the `.bsp` files, and save the text file again.
Edit: This is my new code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import glob
import os

root = Tk()

def Button1():
    mapdirectory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    map = '/maps.txt'
    MapsFile.insert(0, mapdirectory)
    Oldmap.insert(0, mapdirectory + map)


def Button2():
    txtdirectory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    map = '/maps.txt'
    TxTFile.insert(0, txtdirectory + map)

def Button3():
    WD = MapsFile.get()
    os.chdir(WD)
    files = glob.glob('bhop_*.bsp')
    with open('maps.txt', 'w+') as in_files:
        in_files.writelines(os.path.join(fn) + '\n' for fn in files)

    infile = Oldmap.get()
    outfile = TxTFile.get()

    delete_list = [".bsp"]

    fin = open(infile)
    fout = open(outfile, 'w+')
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()



#Label
MapsDirectory = Label(root, text="Maps Directory")
MapsDirectory.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
TxtDirectory = Label(root, text="Maps.txt Directory")
TxtDirectory.grid(row=1, sticky=W)


MapsFile = Entry(root)
MapsFile.grid(row=0, column=1)
TxTFile = Entry(root)
TxTFile.grid(row=1, column=1)
Oldmap = Entry(root)          #If you use oldmap.grid it'll be shown in your Interface
                                 #Without .grid it is hidden 


#Buttons
b1 = Button(text="Choose Map Folder", command=Button1)
b1.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)

b2 = Button(text="Choose txt Folder", command=Button2)
b2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)

b3 = Button(text="Create Maps.txt", command=Button3)
b3.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `bind` doesn't work this way. Besides `Button` doesn't need `bind("<Button-1>",...)` because it has `command=`

Comment: Put old "non-GUI" code inside `def Button3():` and it should works. Later you have to get values from `MapsFile` and `TextFile` to use it in `Button3`

Comment: Furas, thank you for your fast answer. I tried it, but how do i get the values from MapsFile and TextFile?

Comment: it is `Entry` widget so use `MapsFile.get()`. See [Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) in [An Introduction to Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm)

Comment: Thank you again for your fast answer. I tried it yet and it worked. But I've a new problem with `infile = MapsFile.get()` I get PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. Of course it cant work, without having the real Path for the `maps.txt`, so how can I add it to `infile = MapsFile.get()` ?

Comment: See your code in function `Button1` - you already use `MapsFile.insert(...)` to put text in `MapsFile` :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Im rly grateful :)